# Which of the three properties controlling the lifetime of a cookie takes precedence?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

By setting `AuthenticationProperties.IsPersistent` to true we make *authentication cookie* persistent and as such user doesn't have to authenticate again when starting a *new session*

`CookieAuthenticationOptions.ExpireTimeSpans` controls how long the cookie is valid.

`AuthenticationProperties.ExpiresUtc` sets the expiration date of authentication

**a)** I'm not sure what is meant by "*the expiration date of authentication*". Is perhaps the above quote saying that `ExpiresUtc` controls how long can *authentication cookie* can be used for *authentication* before user is again required to *login*?

**b)** If my assumption in **a)** is correct, then when `ExpireUtc` is reached, then *cookie* will expire even if:

- `IsPersistent == true` **and**
- *session* hasn't yet expired and
- cookie hasn't yet exceeded lifespan set by `ExpireTimeSpan`?

**c)** If `IsPersistent` is set to `false`, then as soon as *session expires*, the *cookie* is no longer valid even if:

- cookie hasn't yet exceeded lifespan set by `ExpireTimeSpan` and
- authentication hasn't yet reached the lifespan set by `ExpireUtc` ?

**d)** When cookie exceeds the lifespan set by ExpireTimeSpan, the cookie is no longer valid even if:

- `IsPersistent == true` **and**
- session hasn't yet expired and
- authentication hasn't yet reached the lifespan set by `ExpireUtc` ?

thank you

Answer (score 3):

If `AuthenticationProperties.IsPersistent` is false

- The cookie expiration is set to Session
- Ignore `CookieAuthenticationOptions.ExpireTimeSpans`
- Ignore `AuthenticationProperties.ExpiresUtc`

Otherwise

If there is no `AuthenticationProperties.ExpiresUtc` set

- The cookie expiration is set to `CookieAuthenticationOptions.ExpireTimeSpans`, which defaults to [14 days](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationOptions.cs#L32)

If there is `AuthenticationPropertise.ExpiresUtc` set

- The cookie expiration is set to that
- Ignore `CookieAuthenticationOptions.ExpireTimeSpans`

Answer (score -1):

In case of Identity Framework, there is a property ExpireTimeSpan and it suggest the life time of the cookie. As per below sample, cookie will be invalidated after 24 hours from now.

```
    public static void ConfigureOAuthSettings(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            SlidingExpiration = false,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(24)
        });}
```

If you want to get more detailed code, visit [here](https://github.com/rahulgarg1985/CodeNode.Identity/blob/master/CodeNode.Identity/IdentityStartUp.cs)

Comment: Hardly enough information given the detail of the question.